# Hive not respecting mapreduce.job.reduces

Tags: hadoop, hive

A hive insert statement of the following form:

```
 insert into my_table select * from my_other_table;
```

is using ONE reducer - even though just prior the following had been executed:

```
 set mapreduce.job.reduces=80;
```

Is there a way to force hive to use more reducers? there is not clear reason why this particular query would do a single reducer - given there is no ORDER BY clause at the end.

BTW the source and destination tables are both

```
  stored as parquet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table;` in Hive does not use any reducers - it is a map-only job.

One way to force Hive to use reducers in a `SELECT *` is to `GROUP BY` all of the fields, for example:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table GROUP BY field1, field2, field3;
```

Though, note that this will remove duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

In the insert query you mentioned hive will try to write all the data into a single file. cause its just a select * statement. Hence 1 reducer.

But if you use bucketing. hive will use the same number of reducers as your buckets.

If you have 128 buckets hive will fire 128 reducer jobs and ultimately it will create 128 files.